# Integer out of JSON Object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

so I was trying to get an Integer out of my JSON String but I havent succeeded yet.
JSON Object:

```
{"batchcomplete":"","query":{"pages":{"-1":{"ns":0,"title":"asadsda","missing":""}}}}
```

The Number i would like to save is "-1".
I already parsed the JSON object.
like this:

```
var json = JSON.parse(JSONobject);
```

Hope you can help me!

Comment: Run this in chrome/ Firefox console and see

Comment: `console.log(Number(Object.keys(json.query.pages)[0]));`

Comment: @baao works perfectly! Thanks!